# Использование JS для фронт-энда в Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, frontend

Делаю на Django сайт, с бэк эндом все вроде ясно, но я хочу сверстать красивую хорошие странички, а для этого мне нужен JS, подскажите как мне подключить js, jquery и тд[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так же, как в обычную html-страницу. С чем конкретно у вас возникла проблема?

Comment: Правильно ли я все буду делать, я читал, что нужно юзать Angular, React и тд но я хз как прикрутить все это к сайту, что б не сломать сайт и мозг. Если есть хорошая статья в которой вы уверены по созданию Django(beck-end) и JS(front-end), буду рад почитать ее и я

Comment: Нужно "юзать" то, что нужно для решения конкретной задачи. Есть проекты в которых вообще js не нужен, есть такие в которых React избыточен, есть такие в которых jQuery недостаточна. За статьями лучше обратиться в Google.

Comment: Что бы юзать Angular, React, нужен rest framework. Это может быть Django rest framework или django-tastypie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подключение `jquery` в `index.html`:

```
{% block extrahead %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
{% endblock extrahead %}
```

или, если локально:

```
{% block extrahead %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}">
{% endblock extrahead %}
```

Остальные библиотеки - аналогично.

["Hello world"](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html) - статья по django+ajax+json - для старта вполне сгодится.

И еще. Попробуйте создать пустой проект из шаблона (выбирайте здесь: https://github.com/rosarior/awesome-django#boilerplate) - и получите "из коробки" готовый фронт.
Успехов в изучении!

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/195890)

Comment: ну и чтобы два раза не вставать. проекты можно создавать из шаблонов. https://django-edge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ или https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . там уже многое сделано за вас, и сделано хорошо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для размещения дополнительной информации (в идеале должно быть так, что можно все комментарии стереть, и никакая важная информация, относящаяся к вопросам/ответам не потеряется). Поэтому лучше отредактировать ответ и добавить информацию в него.